# splitting characters of a string by a delimiter in those characters

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string with this pattern: repeat of a char in `[' ', '.', "#"]` plus space.

For example: `# .   #`.

I want to split this string based on space separator (getting `['#', '.', ' ', '#']` but the problem is that space is one of characters itself, so `split(" ")` doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: `# .   #` does not fit to your definition; the last `#` is not followed by space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use comprehensions here - you can just use a stepping slice:

```
>>> text = "# .   #"
>>> text[::2]
'#. #'
>>> list(text[::2])
['#', '.', ' ', '#']
```

Comment: Works like a charm as long as you don't have **three** spaces after one another.

Comment: To avoid confusion, shadowing the builtin and to promote good practices - I'd suggest renaming `str` to `text` or something...

Comment: @Torxed: Erm, the example I used __has__ three spaces after one another. What I think your saying is _"Works as long as the input matches the specification"_

Comment: @JonClements: Whoops, not paying attention there

Answer (score 0):

If your string always has a `(char,space,char,space,...)` sequence, you can do:

`new_list = [old_string[x] for x in range(0,len(old_string),2)]`

```
>>> old_string = '# # # .   #'
#Run code above
>>> print new_string
['#','#','#','.',' ','#']
```

Comment: He mentioned he has a `<char><space><char><space><space><char>` sequence.

Comment: @alireza, I updated my answer to make it simpler and a `one-liner`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for c in yourString:
    if c == ' ' and result[-1] == ' ':
        continue
    result.append(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming exactly one space delimiter between each word, the below would work as well

```
str = "# .   #."
result = []
for index,c in enumerate(str):
    if index%2==0:
       result.append(c)
```